# Silence in Shakespeare's "The Winter's Tale" and "The Tempest"

Tags: william-shakespeare, the-tempest, the-winters-tale

I'd like to know what silence means in those two plays, especially when performed by Leontes and Antonio. Does it have a particular meaning, is it a sign of redemption or regret?

([*The Winter's Tale* act 5 scene 3](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/winters_tale/winters_tale.5.3.html) for Leontes' silence and [*The Tempest* act 5 scene 1](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/tempest/tempest.5.1.html) for Antonio's.)